# Developing for iPhone OS 3 and 4 on XCode 3.1.2

Tags: iphone, xcode, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

I am new to iPhone programming and have a MacBook running Leopard with XCode 3.1.2. I want to use CoreData to read and write to plists, but I read on http://tapity.com/iphone-app-development/readwrite-data-on-the-iphone-property-lists-sqlite-or-core-data/ that CoreData is only available on iPhone OS 3.0. Right now, I am developing for iOS 2.2.1. Is there any way I can develop for iOS 3.0 or even iOS 4.0 with Leopard or do I need to upgrade to Snow Leopard?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should upgrade. Apple approves apps only if they have been built against the latest sdk (even if the target os is a major release back). So, basically, you have no choice if you plan to submit your app to the store ultimately.

Comment: Thanks, Toastor! I also wanted to confirm, is it true that I can't use CoreData on my current version of XCode?

Comment: You're mixing things up a little - Core Data is available in XCode 3.1.2, but it is not supported on devices running with a version of iOS older than 3.0. So the version of XCode doesn't matter anyway as long as you need to develop for iOS 2.2.1.
I suggested upgrading only because with your current version of XCode you won't be able to submit your app to the store..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can use the latest version of the iOS SDK with the version of XCode you have installed, but that would be an obvious solution. I'm sure you should be able to use at least an early version of the 3.0 SDK with XCode 3.1.

However, I would recommend that you upgrade anyway - there are a lot of other useful features in more recent XCode updates, and Snow Leopard should give you better performance on your existing hardware anyway.